# Host Url in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight

I have a silverlight application **in** a browser.
I want to open a url inside my application.

I've seen solutions that involve javascript and divs in the html file, it's not good for me since I don't have access to the HTML file in our project. I'm only developing my module which should be hosted in the end via MEF in the shell project.

In addition, I've seen that the webbrowser control working only in OOB applications.

Any help with be much appritiated.

Comment: Did you make any progress on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[take a look at the solution here](http://www.wintellect.com/cs/blogs/jlikness/archive/2010/09/19/hosting-html-in-silverlight-not-out-of-browser.aspx).

You said you don't have the facility to change the HTML file, but that's no problem. Using the HTML Bridge, I was able to modify the example from Jeremy Likness (linked), and removed the following line from his html:

```
<div id="htmlHost" style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute;"></div>
```

Then recreated it in C# in the constructor for the `HtmlHost` class, as he calls it.

```
HtmlElement myDiv = HtmlPage.Document.CreateElement("div");
myDiv.SetAttribute("id", "htmlHost");
myDiv.SetAttribute("style", "visibility: hidden; position: absolute;");
HtmlPage.Document.Body.AppendChild(myDiv);
```

This gives you the effect you want without needing access to the original HTML.